# Combining 2 Private sub on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to record the value that changes every one minute from cell "B2" into cell "D2". When the values are recorded to "D2" in a row, I want to add the date and time at the same time it recorded into cell "E". Here, below is my code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Me.Range("D" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Me.Range("B2").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim targetRng As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Integer
    
    Set targetRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("D:C"), Target)
    c = 1
    
    If Not targetRng Is Nothing Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       For Each rng In targetRng
          If Not VBA.IsEmpty(rng.Value) Then
             rng.Offset(0, c).Value = Now
             rng.Offset(0, c).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy, hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
          Else
             rng.Offset(0, c).ClearContents
          End If
       Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    End If
End Sub
```

It seems that every time the value has recorded, the date and time in cell "E" do not appear to work together.
Any solution here?

Comment: Hi, maybe because when you change value in B column your "Set targetRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("D:C"), Target)" is probably Nothing, and there you have IF which checks targetRng and it goes to End If, have you tried to debug? :)
If you change value in D column date should be written in E.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a seperate Sub that is not directly hit by an event. Rewrite code below for your purposes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   SharedSheetEvent()
end sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   EditingSheet = true
   call SharedSheetEvent()
   editingsheet = false
end sub

global EditingSheet as bool

public Sub SharedSheetEvent()
   if (EditingSheet) Then
      do some stuff
   else 
      do some other stuff
   end if
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will do what you want. No two procedures are needed but if you don't specify the sheet, meaning you let it work on the ActiveSheet, it would be a bit of a lose cannon.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim LastRecord      As Range            ' cell last written to
    Dim NewValue        As Variant          ' current value in B2
    
    Debug.Print "calculate"
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")               ' change to suit
        Set LastRecord = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)
        NewValue = .Cells(2, "B").Value
        
        With LastRecord
            If .Value <> NewValue Then      ' skip if no change
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Offset(1).Value = NewValue
                With .Offset(1, 1)
                    .Value = Now()
                    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy, hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
                End With
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The question is not, however, how the code works but when. I presume that B2 is changed by a program that works on a timer. The change generated by it doesn't trigger the Worksheet's Change event. You did find out, however, that it triggers the Calculate event. That is my presumption and I couldn't test it. If that is so my procedure will solve your problem.

I have programmed a similar thing recently using a timer of my own to trigger running my procedure. It's just a timer that runs at the same interval as the other and checks every minute (for example) if B2 has changed and records the change if there was one. That works. But if your updater triggers the Calculate event that looks like a neater idea.